Stochastic Integral: Why is $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} B_{x_i}[B_{x_{i+1}}-B_{x_i}]=\frac{1}{2} B_{t_n}^2-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} [B_{x_{i+1}}-B_{x_i}]^2$?
I was working with this explanation of the Stochastic Integral where both functions are Brownian Motion. $$\int_0^t B(x) \, \mathrm{d}(B)x$$
So they wanted to develop this expression, to show how the integration in this case works.
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} B_{x_i} [B_{x_{i+1}}-B_{x_i}] $$
So the next step is this equation:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} B_{x_i} [B_{x_{i+1}}-B_{x_i}] =\frac{1}{2} B_{t_n}^2 -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} [B_{x_{i+1}}-B_{x_i}]^2 $$
Could anyone explain me how do we get from that left side to the expression on the right side?
Thank you a lot!

You might be interested by the 3rd example in my big-list question about connection between discrete and continuous phenomena.

For the sake of simplicity of notation let
$$
\Delta B_{x_i} = B_{x_{i+1}} - B_{x_i}
$$
In general, if we consider a sequence $\{a_i\}$ on which we define $\Delta a_i := a_{i+1} - a_i$ then
\begin{align*}
\newcommand{\D}{\Delta}
\newcommand{\para}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
\Delta \para{ a_i^2 } 
&= a_{i+1}^2 - a_{i}^2 \\
&= a_{i+1}^2 - a_{i}^2 \underbrace{+ 2a_{i+1} a_{i} - 2a_{i+1} a_{i } + 2a_{i}^2 - 2a_{i}^2 }_{=0} \\
&= a_{i+1}^2 - 2a_{i+1} a_{i } + a_{i}^2 + 2a_{i+1}a_{i } - 2a_{i}^2 \\
&= (a_{i+1} - a_{i})^2 + 2 a_{i } (a_{i+1} - a_{i }) \\
&= (\D a_{i})^2 + 2 a_{i } \D a_{i}
\end{align*}
so
$$
a_{i} \D a_{i} = \frac{\D \para{ a_{i}^2 } - (\D a_{i})^2}{2}
$$
Now note that
$$
X := \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} B_{x_i} [B_{x_{i+1}}-B_{x_i}]
= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} B_{x_i} \Delta B_{x_i}
$$
and use the previous identity to get
$$
X = \frac 1 2 \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \para{ B_{x_{i+1}}^2 - B_{x_{i}}^2 }
- \frac 1 2 \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \para{ B_{x_{i+1}} - B_{x_i} }^2
$$
The first sum telescopes and should you to the desired conclusion (provided you have an initial assumption of $B_{x_1}=0$ I believe).

Addendum: I chased myself through this calculation a few years ago for a final exam/project in a stochastic processes class. I was able to find my notes from the derivation back then and this is mostly a copy-and-paste/summary of them. However, in the notes I used the backwards difference in lieu of the forward difference you use. If seeing the difference in notation helps, e.g. if I made a reindexing error above, then the PDF is at this link, see Section $3.4$, example $5$.

That definitely makes sense, thank you very much for your response, you have been helpful and very kind
